# How to convert polygons to line segments using Python

Tags: python, polygon, line, geopandas, explode

I have one shapefile with building polygons.
I would like to convert them into lines split at each vertex, keeping the original source info as an attribute (Name).

```
    Name    category    height_ag   geometry
0   B10896  INDUSTRY    4   POLYGON ((489992.850 14287143.893, 489993.278 ...
1   B11115  SCHOOL_PT   4   POLYGON ((490120.908 14287231.826, 490122.609 ...
2   B11119  SCHOOL_PT   10  POLYGON ((490148.096 14287244.259, 490149.716 ...
3   B11148  SCHOOL_PT   10  POLYGON ((490139.029 14287275.704, 490131.278 ...
4   B10891  SCHOOL_PT   3   POLYGON ((490014.815 14287143.950, 490018.570 ...
```

I tried `df.explode()` from geopandas - but I believe it is not suitable for polygons.
I know that QGIS does this for instance but I need to do it in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .boundary method to convert the polygons to lines, and .coords to fetch the coordinates of each line segment. Then .explode:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

df = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/buildings_con.shp')
df['geometry'] = df.geometry.boundary
dfline = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=df, geometry='geometry')

def explodeLine(row):
    """A function to return all segments of a line as a list of linestrings"""
    coords = row.geometry.coords #Create a list of all line node coordinates
    parts = []
    for part in zip(coords, coords[1:]): #For each start and end coordinate pair
        parts.append(LineString(part)) #Create a linestring and append to parts list
    return parts
        
dfline['tempgeom'] = dfline.apply(lambda x: explodeLine(x), axis=1) #Create a list of all line segments
dfline = dfline.explode('tempgeom') #Explode it so each segment becomes a row (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

dfline = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=dfline, geometry='tempgeom')
dfline = dfline.drop('geometry', axis=1)
dfline.crs = df.crs #Dont know why this is needed
```

[image]

Comment: That isnt clear in your question. I have added a solution for this aswell